[[assume]] attribute not having an impact on code
I expect the multiply_by_pow_of_2 function below to have a more optimized code for multiplication since I used the [[ assume( std::has_single_bit( multiplier ) ) ]]; which is supposed to tell the compiler that 2nd parameter multiplier is always a power of 2. So maybe it could generate faster code. However it generates the same code (using imul):
multiply_by_pow_of_2(unsigned int, unsigned int):
        mov     eax, esi
        imul    eax, edi
        ret

With that said, calling this function in main and comparing its generated code with that of argc * 8 shows that both change to the usual lea (and not to something like a shift left):
        lea     esi, [0+rdi*8]

Here (live):
#include <bit>
#include <cstdio>


unsigned multiply_by_pow_of_2( unsigned num, unsigned multiplier ) noexcept
{
    [[ assume( std::has_single_bit( multiplier ) ) ]];
    return num * multiplier;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[ ] )
{
    unsigned result;

    if constexpr ( true )
    {
        result = multiply_by_pow_of_2( argc, 8 );
    }
    else
    {
        result = argc * 8;
    }

    std::printf( "%d\n", result );
}

which gives (using -O3):
multiply_by_pow_of_2(unsigned int, unsigned int):
        mov     eax, esi
        imul    eax, edi
        ret
.LC0:
        .string "%d\n"
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        lea     esi, [0+rdi*8] ; <- here
        xor     eax, eax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    printf
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret

The function's code remains the same with or without the assumption statement. Am I failing to convince the compiler that multiplier is a power of 2? How can this be done?

First, multiplication instructions are so fast on current CPUs that it isn’t necessarily a big win to use shifts over multiplies.
Second, to replace a multiplication by a shift, it isn’t enough to know that the operand has a single bit — you need to know at what bit position (say b) that bit is actually placed, so you can perform a left shift by b positions. If the compiler can’t infer that information, it’d need to e.g. emit a count trailing zeros instruction to find b, followed by the shift. And that’d be almost certainly more expensive than just the multiply.
On the other hand, if the input is a constant, then the compiler can compute b in compile-time and emit the multiplication-less code as you witnessed.

Right. However couldn't it replace imul with lea inside the function? It knows the operand is a power of 2 so [0+rdi*multiplier] is probably valid too, right?

No. The multiplier is built into the instruction opcode. It is not something you can change at runtime. So the only way you could do that is by either code generation on the fly (yuck) or outputting each and every different power of 2 as an individual instruction and jumping to it (yuck).

@MikeVine Interesting. So I guess the compiler is right in this case. There is no way to avoid imul in the function.
